# laravel [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm not using any vue component in my app i just use `app.js` file in order to compile my npm packages to my assets `js/app.js` or `css/app.css` but i'm getting `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:` error in console.

I'm not sure why is that!

## Code

app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import clipboard from 'clipboard';

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

`Layout`

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container-scroller">
           @include('admin.partials.navbar')
           @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`blades`

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
data
@endsection
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the `console.error` show a trace or a line # in your code for reference? I know in chrome the console outputs gives the file and line number where the output is generated. That would help pinpoint where the error is coming from

Comment: @TrevorVarwig no is just linked to app.js this line `console.error(("[Vue warn]: " + msg + trace));`

Comment: Ok. I don't see any issue with your code that posted. If you remove the `example-component` do you get the same message?

Comment: look like you using an component:  Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

Comment: @EmtiazZahid that's by default installed, i didn't call that component anywhere so is unused

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## SOLVED

Yet i'm not sure why but i added `Vue.use(clipboard);` and it has stopped to show error.